# Pulumi C#: access stackname before RunAsync

Tags: c#, pulumi

Is there a way with Pulumi to access the current stack name in order to chose which class to run when doing pulumi up?

I want to do something like that:

```
static Task<int> Main()
{
    if (Deployment.Instance.StackName.StartsWith("local-"))
        return Deployment.RunAsync<LocalStack>();

    return Deployment.RunAsync<AzureStack>();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Deployment.Instance` is not available before you execute `RunAsync`, which you already figured out.

As a workaround, you could get the stack name from the environment variable:

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PULUMI_STACK")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Deployment.RunAsync<TStack>()`, you can use the `Deployment.RunAsync(Action action)` to define the stack, and the `Deployment.Instance` will have the expected value in the action body (the action is usually a `() => { /* stack definition */ }` lambda), i.e.:

```
internal class Program
{
  private static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
  {
    return await Deployment.RunAsync(() =>
    {
      var stackName = Deployment.Instance.StackName;
      var myResoure = new ...
```